# iOS: Reading Data out of a xml, generated via php-script into objective-c

Tags: php, objective-c, xml, json, nsxmlparser

i have a php script which connects to a MySQL-Database and generates a
XML. The XML holds the Data which i select from the Database.
My Question now is how to start the php script and then get the data
out of the php script generated XML.

I got no idea how to do this, maybe you can help me.

PHP-Script:

```
// DB Connect

$connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbName, $connection);
$result = mysql_query($query);
mysql_close ($connection);


// XML Output

header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?php
echo '<standing version="1.0">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<'.$row['object_id'].'>
      <term_taxonomy>'.$row['taxonomy'].'</term_taxonomy>
      <description>'.$row['description'].'</description>
      <post_date>'.$row['post_date_gmt'].'</post_date>
      <post_content>'.$row['post_content'].'</post_content>
      <post_title>'.$row['post_title'].'</pst_title>
      <post_exerpt>'.$row['post_exerpt'].'</post_exerpt>
    </'.$row['object_id'].'>';
}
echo '</standing>';
?>
```

Maybe you have any code snippets or tutorials how to do this!

Thanks a lot, you would save my Live!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your script available through a URL and then call it within your app.
Check out the documentation for NSURL, NSURLConnection and NSXMLParser.
Just retrieve your data from the URL and then parse it with the XML parser.
[Here](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html) is a tutorial on parsing.
Hope this helps.

Comment: That helps pretty much, thank you. But how do i call/start the php-scipt , just by adding a NSURL and then making a request?

Comment: That's right ! I did it for consuming a PHP-JSON web service. I simply echoed the answer at the end of the script. On the other side I set up a NSURLConnection pointing on the URL of the script.The NSURLConnection delegate stored the data into NSMutableData. I just had to parse it...

Comment: Peter, did you try running your script via NSURLConnection ?

Comment: Now iam on the right lane, thanks, iam calling it via NSURLConnection. What doesnt help anyway, cause i have a error on the php script ;).